# Difference in attitude towards behavior - Accept vs. change

Tags: behavior

I have quite a low threshold for doing mundane tasks, which sometimes taxes my patience a lot. It's been like this since childhood, but varies from day to day and is generally not a serious issue, but when looking for ways to improve, I've noticed two distinct differences in attitude towards the problem:

1. *"This is how you function, and you must adapt your life to it."*
2. *"You must learn how to handle these situations in a better way."*

Attitude 1 seems to conclude that there are something fundamental within me that I have to accept and figure out how to live with.

Attitude 2 seems to have the idea that I can reshape my mindset to where I can accept the situation (maybe even feel joy about it?), no matter how hard and painful it may be.

I'm looking for a basis in psychology about these two attitudes. Which one seems to have a bigger success rate regarding well-being and being able to function better? Is there a middle ground, and how to walk the line between them?

If there are droves of literature about this already, I'm happy for some pointers in the right direction!